# Getting error, when scan the data from unity catalog to purview

Tags: azure-purview, databricks-unity-catalog

when I scan the data from unity, default scan rules are coming and selecting automatically,
[image]
and because of the scan rules my scanning completed with errors.
[image]
But data ingestion is ok. error is coming from billing.usage table because of date format: Timestamp,ErrorCode,OperationName,OperationItem,Message2024-03-08T12:26:46.350Z,FailToConnect,ReadData,databricks://adb-5159569612410553.13.azuredatabricks.net/da981d27-d47a-4a28-bc27-21c0f8094eea/dpwp_dev/system_logging/billing_usage,"[Databricks]DatabricksJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: [CANNOT_UP_CAST_DATATYPE] org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [CANNOT_UP_CAST_DATATYPE] Cannot up cast system.billing.usage.usage_metadata from ""STRUCT<cluster_id: STRING, job_id: STRING, warehouse_id: STRING, instance_pool_id: STRING, node_type: STRING, job_run_id: STRING, notebook_id: STRING, dlt_pipeline_id: STRING>"" to ""STRUCT<cluster_id: STRING, job_id: STRING, warehouse_id: STRING, instance_pool_id: STRING, node_type: STRING, job_run_id: STRING, notebook_id: STRING>""."

But I do not want to select a scan rule set or I would like to make an exemption, if there is no solution for that which scan rule i can set?

I created a custom scan rule set which has no rule: [image]
and applied this scan, I got same error.